# Como usar Jquery Custom Scrollbar em elementos com display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ele não monta a barra de scroll em elementos que estão com "display: none". Alguém sabe como resolver?

[Aqui o plugin do scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)

Comment: Por acaso tem algum exemplo de código para nos mostrar que ficaria mais fácil para ajudar?

Comment: Será necessário um exemplo pra entendimento desta pergunta, em teoria se um elemento tem `display: none` o DOM não calcula dimensões e composição desse elemento, sem isso não é possível adicionar um scroll nele.

Answer (score 1):

Coloca um handler pros seus elementos pra quando eles forem exibidos:

```
$('.elemento').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':visible')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollButtons: {
            enable: true
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O elemento só pode ser utilizado pelo jQuery quando o elemento estiver comi display:block ou algo similar, Você poderia tentar aplicar a custom Scrollbar assim que o elemento for exibido.

Faça a pergunta assim mesmo: Qual a ação realizada para que você consiga aplicar o custom scrollbar? "é no evento click de algum elemento que está sendo exibido", logo chame a montagem da custom scrollbar no evento.